# Identification (and removal) of item showing on screen (& not part of a layer)

Tags: qgis

I have somehow managed to get these two points on my screen, together with a label (1 and 2) (see image).

They stay even when all layers are unchecked (even though everything else vanishes). They do not appear to be 'labels' as none of my layers have labels on. They still appear when viewing the layout.

Potential source: I was having issues with my underlying road network and had had to add in two lines manually, and was not managing to get them to snap properly so I was trying quite a few things.

Could someone be so kind as to tell me the terminology for these 'points' so I can search for the term, and then hopefully figure out how to delete them?

[image: Screen-snip of the offending items]

Comment: These look like annotation, try to interact with them using the annotation toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the Annotations toolbar is enabled

Click the Text annotation button

[image]

[image]

Click on the text

[image]

Press the `Delete` (or `Del`) button on the keyboard.

[image]